# Why is the list of relationships presented when adding an additional role to a case different from those presented when configuring a case?

Tags: civicase

The list of relationships presented for selection when configuring a case type are B to A Relationships. The list available from which to add roles to cases contains A to B relationships. Is this correct? Why don't these lists present the same perspective of the relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a JIRA issue [CRM-16980](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16980) which is listed as fixed in 4.7.